# can get mac address of wifi with react Native? (when not connect to wifi)

Tags: reactjs, macos, react-native, mobile, ssid

I want to have unique wifi name from my database. can i get mac address or BSSID by react Native?
i want to select technolojy of react native if it can do this .is there any body to help me

Answer (score 1):

React Native library for getting information about the device's network

[react-native-network-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-network-info)

```
import { NetworkInfo } from 'react-native-network-info'

// Get BSSID
NetworkInfo.getBSSID(bssid => {
  console.log(bssid);
});
```